# Travelling to Phillipines before valid on date in Schengen visa

Tags: visas

Can anyone please advice whether I may be permitted to enter Phillipines before the Valid on date stamped in my Schengen visa and obtain a visa on arrival in Philippines?
i.e., my Schengen visa validity is from 13 May 2018 till 05 June 2018. Can I go to Phillipines on the 7th May 2018?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Philippines are not part of Schengen, why do you think the validity of your Schengen visa affects travel to the Philippines?

Comment: @henrik Indian (and possibly others) holding certain third-country visas including Schengen visas can enter the Philippines visa free for fourteen days. I'd guess this is the relevance.

Comment: @InsanityRules: Okay, but then the OP should have remember to state his nationality.

Comment: @Lokesh What is your nationality? When do you plan to leave the Philippines and are you going from the Philippines to your Schengen destination or returning to your country of origin first?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.